# Cannot get outfile to work in C++ in Windows

Tags: c++, file-io

For some reason outfile is not outputting a txt file in Windows. It has worked fine on the Mac (the line that's commented out in the code below), but in Windows I can't get it to output. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int iNumberOfEmployees(); // this function prompts the user for the number of employees.
int iMissedDays(int employees); // this function prompts the user for the number of days each employee missed and returns the total.
double dAverageMissedDays(int employees, double missedDays); // this function calculates the average missed days per employee.

int main() {
    int iGetEmployees = iNumberOfEmployees();
    int iGetMissedDays = iMissedDays(iGetEmployees);
    cout << "Average missed days: "<< dAverageMissedDays(iGetEmployees,iGetMissedDays) << endl;

    // outputs results to a text file
    ofstream outfile;
//  outfile.open ("/Users/chrisrukan/Documents/CS140/Project 3/output.txt");
    outfile.open ("C:\CS140\Project 3\output.txt");
    if (outfile.is_open()) {
      outfile << "Average missed days: "<< dAverageMissedDays(iGetEmployees,iGetMissedDays);
      outfile.close();
    }
    else {
      cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
    }
}

int iNumberOfEmployees () {
    int iTotalEmployees = 0;

    // loop checks that the user doesn't enter a negative number of employees
    while (iTotalEmployees <= 0) {
        cout << "Enter the number of employees: ";
        cin >> iTotalEmployees;
    }
    return iTotalEmployees;
}

int iMissedDays (int iEmployees) {
    int iTotalMissedDays = 0;
    int iIndividualMissedDays;

    // loop asks the user the missed days for each individual employee
    for (int i = 1; i <= iEmployees; i++) {
        iIndividualMissedDays = -1;

        // loop checks that user doesn't enter a negative number
        while (iIndividualMissedDays < 0) {
            cout << "Enter employee " << i << "'s number of missed days: ";
            cin >> iIndividualMissedDays;
        }
        iTotalMissedDays += iIndividualMissedDays;
    }
    return iTotalMissedDays;
}

double dAverageMissedDays (int iEmployees, double dMissedDays) {
    return dMissedDays / iEmployees;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows, file path are separated by `\`, you also need an extra `\` if you need to pass file path as parameter to a function.

**EDIT:** according to @Benjamin Lindley, forward slashes will work on Windows too provided that the path is right.

There is also no root directory `/` as in Linux.

```
outfile.open ("/Users/chrisrukan/Documents/CS140/Project 3/output.txt");
```

Try to replace the string `"/Users/chrisrukan/Documents/CS140/Project 3/output.txt"` with windows file path format, absolute path starting from Disk name. e.g.,

`"C:\\Users\\chrisrukan\\Documents\\CS140\\Project 3\\output.txt"`.

Or

```
`"C:/Users/chrisrukan/Documents/CS140/Project 3/output.txt"`
```

make sure those directories do exist.

Comment: Forward slashes will work in Windows too, as long as you have the right path.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Good to know this point, I never really realized that it will also work with forward slashes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem.  However, minor correction.  If you use forward slashes, you don't need to double them up.  You only do it with back slashes because it's the escape sequence character.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley another great point that broaden my knowledge scope, thanks!

Comment: Thanks much for the help. It's much appreciated. This was driving me nuts.

Comment: @ChrisRukan You are very welcome. I am glad that I got a chance to learn from Benjamin because of your question.

Answer (score 1):

A backslash in C++ is actually language syntax, for example \n means: new line, \t means: tab, in order to actually have a "\" in a string (as it stands right now you have a \C, \P, and \o which by the way all are considered one character each) you must type two \'s, for example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "\\";
}
```

outputs:

```
\
```

Also just a tip, files will automatically (by default if no other path is specified) be outputted/written to wherever the executable is stored.